# Is it possible to know what setters are available in a style in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have downloaded an assembly which has a class. The class exposes a style property to allow customizing appearance. Is it possible to know what are all the possible setter properties it will allow to create the style object? (eg., by looking at disaassmbly, etc.)

EDIT : if not possible, i am also looking for guidelines (eg., finding all dependencyproperty exposed by the class, look at MSIL code of the PutStyle etc.)

Comment: Ummm... have you tried the documentation for said class?

Comment: Couldn't you just use reflection to get all the (publicly declared) dependency properties for the class?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know exactly what your situation was when I read your question.  After looking at it again, it sounds like you are trying to find on what properties can be set in your styles for an object.  That would mean you would be interested in the non-readonly dependency properties that are available on a dependency object.  Of course, there's the caveat that the object might not necessarily use all of the properties to render itself.  So don't be surprised if you set some properties and nothing seems to change.

Just use reflection to search for all `DependencyProperty` fields and get the values (if the objects follow the conventions for declaring dependency properties).  You could use this to get such properties.

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> GetDependencyProperties(DependencyObject owner)
{
    var type = owner.GetType();
    var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
    return type.GetFields(flags)
               .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty))
               .Select(fi => fi.GetValue(null))
               .Cast<DependencyProperty>();
}

// get the non-readonly dependency properties
var writableDPs = GetDependencyProperties(myObject)
    .Where(dp => !dp.ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Mercado's suggestion sounds quite good, e.g. i just used this on a custom control:

```
var props = typeof(PanAndZoomControl).GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
    .Select(x => x.Name);
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", props));
```

[image: A screenshot]

I used a comma delimiter to make it more compact, you could just output that to a text file using `File.WriteAllLines()` or something like that.

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was getting all `DependencyProperties` on the `DependencyObject`, not just the regular vanilla .NET properties.

Comment: You are right, getting only the DependencyProeperties is a lot more clean, i think in most cases they will return the same results though, since on controls you usually only use DPs.